# how to execute complex mysql queries in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have one below mysql query that is working fine but i want to run it laravel using prepare statement.

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("SELECT '",colname,":' AS 'Label',GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attr_details,'$.", colname,"'))) AS 'val' FROM mytable GROUP BY Label") SEPARATOR " UNION ")
       INTO @sql
FROM
(WITH RECURSIVE data AS (
  SELECT attr_details,JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(attr_details), '$[0]') AS colname, 0 AS idx FROM mytable
  UNION
  SELECT attr_details,JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(attr_details), CONCAT('$[', d.idx + 1, ']')) 
  AS colname, d.idx + 1 AS idx FROM data AS d
  WHERE d.idx < JSON_LENGTH(JSON_KEYS(attr_details)) - 1
) SELECT colname
FROM data
GROUP BY colname) V;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;;
```

Now i have tried to convert in larvel like below

```
$PDO=DB::connection('mysql')->getPdo();
            $stmt = $PDO->prepare(<<<_OUT
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("SELECT '",colname,"' AS 'Label',GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attr_details,'$.", colname,"'))) AS 'val' FROM product_attributes GROUP BY Label") SEPARATOR " UNION ")
       INTO @sql
FROM
(WITH RECURSIVE data AS (
  SELECT attr_details,JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(attr_details), '$[0]') AS colname, 0 AS idx FROM product_attributes
  UNION
  SELECT attr_details,JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(attr_details), CONCAT('$[', d.idx + 1, ']')) 
  AS colname, d.idx + 1 AS idx FROM data AS d
  WHERE d.idx < JSON_LENGTH(JSON_KEYS(attr_details)) - 1
) SELECT colname
FROM data
GROUP BY colname) V;
_OUT
);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); die;
```

I am getting this error  **"syntax error, unexpected 'SELECT' (T_STRING), expecting ')'",**
Can anyone help me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("SELECT
                           ^-- this quote must be escaped like this: \"
```

PHP thinks that your SQL string ends there.

Check the other quotes as well.

**Edit:** Other option might be to wrap the whole SQL to single quotes (`'`) and then just escape those inside the query (by `\'`)

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(\"SELECT '\",colname,\"' AS 'Label',GROUP_CONCAT(JSON...' at line 3 Line No. 82

Comment: Your escaping seems incorrect. There will also probably be other errors when using $ sign inside double quotes ("). The best solution might be to wrap the SQL string in single quotes (') and escape other single quotes inside the query like this \'

Comment: Filip Halaxa would appericate if you can post as answer

Comment: can you update my code that i have tried.. it will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check your quotes at first. In the code `"SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("SELECT` PHP recognizes that as complete string "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(" and something undefined `SELECT '` with the next string, without concatenation.

At least for me my IDE highlights your code as incorrect. To deal with various quotes try to use that approach

```
$stmt = $PDO->prepare(<<<_OUT
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE "1";
_OUT
);
```

2. Try to write the request without `@sql` variable, without `PREPARE stm` and without `EXECUTE stm`. I think, PDO will deal with preparing and executing by itself.

   $stmt = $PDO->prepare(<<<_OUT
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT() ...
   FROM data
   GROUP BY colname) V;
   _OUT
   );

   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->fetchAll();
3. Try to use Laravel approach: `DB::select(DB::raw($sql));`

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(\"SELECT '\",colname,\"' AS 'Label',GROUP_CONCAT(JSON...

Comment: i have updated my question and i tried the way you suggested.. but its still having error

Comment: if i remove @sql my output is not coming all query is shwoing

Comment: Did you try to execute that request manually without PHP? If I understood correctly, you are trying to get subquery by concatenation on the SQL side. Probably it worth to re-write that and prepare the sub-query (for select) in ordinary way?

Comment: And try to make search by json field using just `like` operator or using `JSON_CONTAINS`, i.e. `where attr_details like '%something%'`. Probably it will help to simplify the sql request.